# Can we introduce some java or any other language wrapper on top of python code in order to conceal/encrypt our python code from being re-engineered?

Tags: java, python, raspberry-pi, iot

I am currently, working on deep learning algorithm with an objective of devising optimum method for edge devices where trade-off between the accuracy & speed will be minimum. For this reason, I want to hide my code for saving my work being concluded in span of last 6 months from getting public in few minutes. Any other way or hint will be appreciated for doing same.

Comment: A wrapper just *wraps* the contained code; it doesn't stop it from being what it is, and wrappers are generally quite easy to penetrate, whether it's unpacking by-hand or just running the software and then reaching into memory to pull the content out after it's been uncompressed/decrypted/etc.

Comment: Frankly, and I say this as someone who's been responsible for writing more than one DRM tool, you're better off putting your effort into developing new/better functionality rather than worrying about reverse-engineering. Someone willing to pay a good RE team can *always* get your code out; getting the expertise needed to refine that code is more expensive, and a bunch of code without a team of people who understand the algorithms is useless.

Comment: One way to get some perspective is to be involved in the process of buying a software development company's intellectual property out of bankruptcy, and trying to reboot a business on top of it. There's way more to running a software business than just having posession of the source.